# How to set onClick option on twitter typeahead.js search query results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I am new to typeahead.js. I wrote a sample code to retrieve results from database using typeahead. The backend server is running on Node.js.

Here is the typeahead code:-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
                name: 'customers',
                remote: 'http://localhost:3000/searchCustomers?key=%QUERY',
                limit: 10
            });
        });
```

Here is the Node.js API:-

```js
exports.searchCustomers = function(req, res) {
con.connection.query('SELECT * FROM customers WHERE fname LIKE "%' + req.query.key + '%"', function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    var fullName = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        fullName.push(rows[i].fname + " " + rows[i].lname);
    }
    res.send(JSON.stringify(fullName));
})
}
```

When I try looking up a customer name, the results of the query are displayed.

Now, I need to be able to create an onclick on the search results so that I may get the customer information. I have tried several methods, but, I haven't been able to accomplish it. How can I achieve the same?